# How to get all groups of members who distinguishedName begins with something

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query, adgroup

My requirement is to get all the groups of users whose `distinguishedName` begins with say `Auser*`.

So, I created a filter in Apache Directory Studio

```
(&
    (objectClass=group)
    (member=CN=Auser*)
)
```

However, to my surprise, this does not return any results. If I change this to a particular user's `distinguishedName`, I am able to get results

```
(&
    (objectClass=group)
    (member=CN=AUser10,OU=Mygrp,DC=domain,DC=com)
)
```

**Am I missing something ?**

Answer (score 1):

`member` has Distinguished-Name-Syntax, and given it's Active Directory you are trying to search, you can't have substring matching as in a normal Directory-String attribute like `cn`.

Why don't you just reverse your search strategy?  Do a subtree search on your domain with filter `(&(objectClass=user)(cn=userprefix*))` retrieving attribute `memberOf`, export to CSV, remove duplicates, done.

Comment: `memberOf` attribute does not store all the groups of a user (like Domain local aren't stored in `memberOf`). Hence I am querying on groups and not on user

Comment: Use memberOf for what it's worth.  Export the domain local groups and use grep / findstr.

Comment: Yes tht is what I am doing... but wanted a better direct way

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one :

```
(&
    (objectCategory=group)
    (name=Auser*)
)
```

distinguished name is long name containing full path + name. like : `CN=Username,OU=internalFolder,OU=parentFolder,DC=domainComponentName,DC=com`

For filtering by name just search on the name or other attributes you want like givenName